# Having an issue with createClient

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay, so how my code works is that a discord bot in the index.js file has stored usernames and passwords.
When I make a request to the minecraft file, using minecraft-protocol i create a login to a server called Client,

```
        clientName = mc.createClient({ // connect to 2b2t
            host: "2b2t.org",
            port: 25565,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            version: "1.12.2"
        });
```

an issue with this is, when a new user (while the current client is still going) trys to create a client, the old one is dropped for the new one. I need a way to identify one from the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are more than likely overwriting the original connection, causing it to drop. You could instead make a connection factory and be able to create many connections.

```js
class ClientFactory {

    constructor(mc) {
        this.mc = mc;
        this.clients = {};
    }

    create(key, options) {
        const client = this.mc.createClient(options);

        this.clients[key] = client;

        return client;
    }

    get(key) {
        return this.clients[key];
    }

}

// Instantiate factory
const client = new ClientFactory(mc);

// Make first client
client1 = client.create('client1', {
    host: "2b2t.org",
    port: 25565,
    username: username,
    password: password,
    version: "1.12.2"
});

// Make second client
client2 = client.create('client2', {
    host: "2b2t.org",
    port: 25565,
    username: username,
    password: password,
    version: "1.12.2"
});

// Do something with one of them
client.get('client1').callSomething();
```